# When installing Xamarin I get an error message "Invalid Drive F:\"

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, installation

When I attempt to install Xamarin for Visual Studio, I get an error message "Invalid Drive F:\".
I tried by extension manager, standalone install from Xamarin website, same problem...
Does someone know a workaround or solution ?
I have the latest VS2015 Update 3 installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm. It's a bug of installer. Due to my bad English when I saw solution by telling "Start Orb and..." I believed that was an "unknown" application called "Orb" and that solution was not applicable for me.

I found another solution: Insert an USB key or external USB drive which takes "F:\" as drive letter...

Thanks all.

Comment: Since you already found your solution and shared it, you can try to mark it as answer that will help other community members who have the same or similar issue to easier search your solution.

Comment: Start Orb means the Start Menu. The solution in Sara's answer is run the CMD as Administrator and then run "subst F: C:\" command.

Answer (score 0):

To install the Xamarin for VS 2015, you can go to Control Panel—Programs and Features and right click the VS 2015 update 3 item, Change-Modify, then check the option Cross-Platform Mobile Development > C#/.NET (Xamarin) and install it, the installation is successful for my VS professional 2015 with update 3.

Refer to your error message, you can have a look at this similar issue and try the solution as below:

> Miller: Click the Start Orb and type CMD in the search, Right Click
>   the Command Prompt Icon and right Click Run as Administrator. In the
>   Command Prompt type the following: subst F: C:\, then press Enter.